# How to put table in full page when paper format is double column

Tags: tables, longtable, xtable

I am using the double-column paper format, and I've two requirements as follows. 
First, I need my table to be spanned over the whole width of the document not just one column. Second, if a table is longer than the height of a page, its should be broken properly.

Please help.

```
\documentclass[5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ecrc_RIAI}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}     % Idioma
\addto\captionsspanish{%
\def\tablename{Tabla}%
}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{epstopdf}           
\usepackage{flushend}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{supertabular,booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cuted, ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum, array, booktabs, multirow, caption, float,xtab}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\cellset{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{xtabular}{l l l l l l l}

Controller Name & Language & Developer organization & Version & Open Source &   Overview & Reference \\\hline
POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  NTT,OSRG group & 1.5 &  Yes & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
Controller Name & Language & Developer organization & Version & Open Source &   Overview & Reference \\\hline
POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  NTT,OSRG group & 1.5 &  Yes & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
Controller Name & Language & Developer organization & Version & Open Source &   Overview & Reference \\\hline
POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  NTT,OSRG group & 1.5 &  Yes & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
Controller Name & Language & Developer organization & Version & Open Source &   Overview & Reference \\\hline
POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  NTT,OSRG group & 1.5 &  Yes & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
Controller Name & Language & Developer organization & Version & Open Source &   Overview & Reference \\\hline
POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  NTT,OSRG group & 1.5 &  Yes & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
Controller Name & Language & Developer organization & Version & Open Source &   Overview & Reference \\\hline
POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  NTT,OSRG group & 1.5 &  Yes & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN. & ~\cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
 \hline
\end{xtabular}
\end{center}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Can it float ?

Comment: If it can float there is the `\begin{table*}...\end{table*}` environment that allows tables to span both columns.

Comment: @Skillmon My table is bigger than one page, but after adding your suggested command, remaining table is not coming on 2nd page 
Can you tell me how i can manage it?

Comment: Welcome. We need more information about your document, used class and other packages etc. Could you add at least the `\documentclass` and the packages used in the code example please? It is always best to provide a [minimal, but compilable example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/2975) with your questions here.

Comment: @\documentclass[5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}

Comment: @usman1644, not add some fragment in comment. please edit your question and extend your code snippet to complete small document (mwe: minimal working example) which we can copy and test in our computers.

Comment: @Zarko i have added in main body of my post, please help.

Answer (score 1):

so far I've been able to turn your table into the next form:

[image]

in this effort i did the following:

- from preamble remove all packages not needed for writing your table (there you have some packages loaded twice ... and do you really need all those packages?
- use the `X` column type (from the package `tabularx`) for column with cells containing long texts which otherwise spill-out of page
- use `\thead` and `makecell` macros from the package `makecell` for made column headers shorter (using two lines) and also for some cells in the third columns
- use `\small` font size that text in multi line cells better fin in cells

with this measures the table, as you can see above, is a tight fit to text width and is placed on one page.

```
\documentclass[5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}     % Idioma

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\renewcommand\cellalign{tl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\caption{My huge table ...}
\label{fig:myhugetable}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll  ll  l  X l @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{Controller\\ Name}
    &   \thead{Language}
        &   \thead{Developer\\ organization}
            &   \thead{Version}
                & \thead{Open\\ Source}
                    &   \thead{Overview}
                        &   \thead{Reference}       \\
    \midrule
POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
        & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
        & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\

POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
        & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
        & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\

POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
        & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
        & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\

POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
        & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
        & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\

POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
        & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
        & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\

POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
        & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
        & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\

POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
        & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
        & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
        & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
            & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
%\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
if the real table is longer as is considered above, than i suggest the following:

- manually split table into two parts
- use macro `\ContinuedFloat` from the `caption` package which preserve the same caption number in the both table parts.
- use package `stfloats` which enable positioning table on the bottom of the same package where it is inserted:

  ```
  \documentclass[5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \usepackage[spanish]{babel}     
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  \renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\theadgape{}
  \setcellgapes{3pt}
  \renewcommand\cellalign{tl}

  \usepackage{stfloats}

  \usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-4]
      \begin{table*}[b] % <---
      \makegapedcells   % <---
  \caption{My huge table ... (first part)}
  \label{fig:myhugetable}
      \small
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll  ll  l  X l @{}}
      \toprule
  \thead{Controller\\ Name}
      &   \thead{Language}
          &   \thead{Developer\\ organization}
              &   \thead{Version}
                  & \thead{Open\\ Source}
                      &   \thead{Overview}
                          &   \thead{Reference}       \\
      \midrule
  POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
          & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
              & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
  NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
          & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
          & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
  RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
          & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
              & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
  % ...
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
      \end{table*}

      \begin{table*}[t]   % <---
      \ContinuedFloat     % <---
      \makegapedcells
  \caption{My huge table ... (second part)}
  \label{fig:myhugetable}
      \small
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} ll  ll  l  X l @{}}
      \toprule
  \thead{Controller\\ Name}
      &   \thead{Language}
          &   \thead{Developer\\ organization}
              &   \thead{Version}
                  & \thead{Open\\ Source}
                      &   \thead{Overview}
                          &   \thead{Reference}       \\
      \midrule
  POX & Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
          & An Open Flow controller is being supported via SDN controller in general.
              & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_mccauley_nodate}[20],[29]\\
  NOX & C++/Python & Nicira & 1.0 & Yes
          & It is open flow controller. Current NOX is written in C++ and Classic NOX is written in C++ and Python.
          & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,gude_nox:_2008}  [20],[30]\\
  RYU & Python &  \makecell{NTT,\\OSRG group} & 1.5 &  Yes
          & It is SDN OS which provides the centralized control logically. The open Flow v1.0, v1.2 and v1.3 are supported by component RYU that is based on framework of SDN.
              & \cite{masoudi_software_2016,noauthor_ryu_nodate}    [20],[31]\\
  % ...
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{table*}
  \lipsum[5-15]
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]